# Java inheritance with threads confusion

Tags: java, multithreading, inheritance, interface, base-class

I am examining code here which uses inheritance and threads.

There is a BaseCom and ServerCom class as below. The ServerCom class extends the BaseCom class. The BaseCom class implements an interface called Com.

```
public class BaseCom implements Com
{
   protected final Thread thread;
   protected final InetSocketAddress socketAddress;


   public BaseCom(InetSocketAddress socketAddress)
   {
      System.out.println("BaseCom CONSTRUCTOR!!!!");
      this.socketAddress = socketAddress;
      thread = new Thread(() -> run(socketAddress));
   }

   @Override
   public void start()
   {
      System.out.println("HELLO FROM BaseCom start method!!!!");
      thread.start();
   }

   protected void run(InetSocketAddress socketAddress)
   {
      System.out.println("HELLO FROM BaseCom run!!!!");
   }

   //.... more stuff .... not shown here 
}
```

lll

```
public class ServerCom extends BaseCom
{

   public ServerCom(InetSocketAddress socketAddress, long timeOutMs)
   {
      super(socketAddress);
      System.out.println("ServerCom CONSTRUCTOR!!!!");

   }

   @Override
   protected void run(InetSocketAddress socketAddress)
   {
      System.out.println("ServerCom run method!!!!");
   }
   // ... more stuff.. not shown here
}
```

Why is it when I run the following code below from a main function, that actually the run method of the ServerCom class gets executed and not that of the basecom class?

The fact that line `thread = new Thread(() -> run(socketAddress));` is inside the BaseCom class and not the ServerCom class, would make me think that it should be the Basecom run method which gets called.

```
connectorA = new ServerCom(socketAddressA, 1000000);
connectorA.start();
```

Answer (score 4):

The call to `run(...)` is resolved at runtime ([dynamic dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch)). Since the actual type of this `BaseCom` is `ServerCom`, `ServerCom`'s `run(...)` is executed. There is no way to enforce that `BaseCom`'s `run(...)`-method is called if it is overridden (since it is overridden the original method is inaccessible).

The problem is not related to multithreading.

Comment: "There is no way to enforce that BaseCom's run(...)-method is called" you can if you can make the method final.

Comment: @AndyTurner true, but then you cannot override the method ;)

Comment: I still can't understand this one fully. I understand about dynamic resolution of method calls in OO programming, but the run() method here gets called / assigned inside the Basecom class?  "new Thread(() -> run(socketAddress)" , how does it know to use the ServerCom run() method as this stage?

Comment: Let's get technical: a lambda in java is syntactic sugar for an anonymous inner class. Within that class, you call a method `run(...)` - which does not exists. Since it is an inner class, the compiler looks for a method `run(...)` in the outer class - which does exists. Thus, the method `run(...)` from the enclosing class is called - a `this.run(...)` if you want. The reference `this`, however has a type - in your case `ServerCom`. Associated with this type are all its method - inherited and overriden. Thus, in your case `this.run(...)` leads to the execution of `ServerCom`'s `run(...)`-method